# Progress bar for Leaflet map

Tags: javascript, web-mapping, leaflet

Is there any way to show progress bar while waiting that all layers are rendered on Leaflet map? In this specific case, while GeoJSON layers are rendered.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks, but I already found this solution:

https://github.com/makinacorpus/Leaflet.Spin

Comment: That is my answer.

Answer (score 19):

There is the leaflet loading plugin https://github.com/ebrelsford/Leaflet.loading, it is straightforward to use. you could also look at the Spin plugin https://github.com/makinacorpus/Leaflet.Spin which is more customizable.